# How to get a classname along with logs in NestJS using Winston logger

Tags: logging, nestjs, nest-winston

I am using NestJS as a backend service in which I want to add some logger for better logging mechanism.Though NestJs has a default logger for logging but I am using Winston in my application.
I want functionality so I can get a class name also in logs to which log belongs to.

Using NestJs default logger I can achieve this using below code in particular file

```
private readonly logger = new Logger(AppService.name);
```

By using above code I am able to get class name along with logs which is `AppService`.

But I am using nest-winston package in my application. How can I get the same thing with it?

Below is my code:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModule,utilities as nestWinstonModuleUtilities } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
imports: [ WinstonModule.forRoot({
          format: winston.format.combine(
                   winston.format.timestamp(),
                   winston.format.json(),
                   nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike('MyApp', { prettyPrint: true }),
                  ),
          transports: [
                    new winston.transports.Console(),
                    new winston.transports.File({
                      dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../log/info/'), //path to where save logging result 
                      filename: 'info.txt', //name of file where will be saved logging result
                      level: 'info',
                    }),
                  ],        
       }),],
 controllers: [AppController],
 providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What thing do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

The Logger class in `nest-winston` behaves differently than the pre-built Nest logger. You have to pass the service name on every call of either the `log(), debug(), error() and verbose()` methods.

Based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-winston) this is how you can use the winston logger service after you replace it with the nest Logger.

```
import { Controller, Get, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
    private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    this.logger.log('Calling getHello()', AppController.name);
    this.logger.debug('Calling getHello()', AppController.name);
    this.logger.verbose('Calling getHello()', AppController.name);
    this.logger.warn('Calling getHello()', AppController.name);

    try {
      throw new Error()
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error('Calling getHello()', e.stack, AppController.name);
    }

    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```